# 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10038)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, navicat

I installed mysql server in my ubuntu virtual machine, then I use Navaicat for Mysql to connet mysql, but failed.
Navicat for Mysql is installed on Windows 7,
Navicat version is 11.0.10, enterprise edition
mysql is installed in my virtual machine, the system is Ubuntu 12,
when I connect the mysql server, it returns:
[image]

my navicat connection configuration:
[image]

I tried several methods, including use the command: grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identifed by 'passwd' with grant option
and I shutdown the firewall of ubuntu using: ufw disable
and I hava also shutdown the firewall of windows 7, 
the state of port 3306 of the ubuntu server is:
[image]

the iptable rules is like this:
[image]

the mysql.user table is like this:
[image]

but still, the navicat gives me the error:
2003 - can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10038)

anyone can help me? thank you!

Comment: What you response you get, when you enter `192.168.3.164` in windows browser? Is it accessible IP address?

Comment: it's the IP of my ubuntu viritual machine, my windows 7 IP is 192.168.3.133, so I can ping the ubuntu vm successfully

Comment: the ubuntu is installed in the VritualBox of my windows system

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem. In my /etc/mysql/my.cnf, the command bind the locahost address like this:
bind-address=127.0.0.1, just add a # before it. and now I can connect to the mysql server smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `Port Forwarding Rule` in viritual machine configuration, `Settings > Network > Adapter1 > Advanced > "Port Forwarding"`

Comment: In my virtual box, if I want to set the "Port Forwarding", I have to set the Adapter1's mode to NAT, and after I reboot my virtual machine, there is no IP allocated to it.

Comment: I solved this problem, in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf， I delete the bind-address=127.0.01, and noe I can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the `my.cnf` file in path `/etc/mysql/`
2. Find `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` and comment it out like so:

   `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
3. Restart MySQL
4. Now we have a problem with not being allowed to connect to this MySQL server, thus we need to continue
5. Use the following MySQL command:

```sql
    grant all PRIVILEGES on database_name.* to user_name@'%' identified by 'user_password';
```

6. Check the `user_privileges` table in the `information_schema` database and make sure that `user_name` has been added in the table.
7. Login to remote MySQL from local using the `user_name`

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the following options：

- Close firewall temporarily （Recommended）

```
systemctl stop firewall
```

- Or close firewall forever

```
 systemctl disable firewalld
```